# Sending data to a controller with ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send a simple POST request data to a controller, but with ajax. Nothing fancy, I simply want to send data to my controller without the page redirecting/refreshing.

**EDIT:** Updated all of the code to what it currently is

In header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<script>var host="{{url()}}"</script>
```

Route

```
post('/messages/unread', '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\MessageController@getReadRequest');
```

Markup

```
<div class="accordion messageAccordion getRequestReadMessage" data-value="{{$message->id}}">
```

Script

```
$('.getRequestReadMessage').click(function() {
    $readValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $token     = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr("content");
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: host + '/messages/unread',
        data: {readValue: $readValue, _token:$token},
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function getReadRequest(Request $request)
{
    dd(Input::get("readValue"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the method POST, you have to send it a _token, you are probably getting a token mismatch error.

On your header, put this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

On JS

```
$('.getRequestReadMessage').click(function() {
    $readValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $token     = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr("content");
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: host + 'messages/unread',
        data: {readValue: $readValue, _token:$token},
    });
});
```

Your route seems a bit off, though.
update it to:
`post('/messages/unread', '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\MessageController@getReadRequest');`

====EDIT=====

Additionaly, i see that you have that div around a form field, since you are using ajax, its not necessary.

```
<div class="accordion messageAccordion getRequestReadMessage" data-value="{{$message->id}}">
```

What i did was remove the form field and the hidden input, also i removed the type=submit attribute, since its not a button in a form. I algo changed the value attribute in the div, to data-value. Change your JS to this:

```
$readValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
```

EDIT 2

```
$('.getRequestReadMessage').click(function() {
    $readValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $token     = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr("content");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: host + '/messages/unread',
        data: {readValue: $readValue, _token:$token},
    }).success(function (res){
        alert('it work! :D');
    });
});
```

Comment: still getting the error "ReferenceError: host is not defined" in console.

Comment: have you defined the variable host in your JS file or have you defined it anywhere at all?

Comment: I do now! But nothing is happening when I click on .getRequestReadMessage

Comment: i updated my answer, see if it helps :) @FelixMaxime

Comment: Nothing happens, but I do get a 500 error. My original post has been updated with everything up to date, including the laravel error logs.

Comment: 200 is not an error, that means it was OK, onpen inspection in chrome, or firebug on mozilla, refresh the page, click on the button that makes your ajax call, and see what it displays in your network tab, it should spit out the value of readValue

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I do get an error in logs. http://codepaste.net/cttmrs

Comment: did you set your user and password in your .ENV file? DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=my_database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password_if_db_has_password

Comment: I didn't. I've been leaving it root for username and blank for password, and things have been running fine until now.

Comment: what about your database name? forge is the default db name that laravel ships with, also check my update for the ajax call

Comment: the database is called commendme. The registration/login system is working fine with those.

Comment: I get the alert with your new update, but not the dd() from my controller.

Comment: on your controller, change `dd(Input::get("readValue"));` to `return Input::get("readValue")` and on the JS change `alert('it work! :D');` to `alert(res);`

Comment: also, the errors in logs have stopped. No idea why.

Comment: Well, it works. I was just confused as to why the dd() command wasn't working (and still isn't). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The Ajax part itself seems just fine.
Make sure you have the `host` defined somewhere in the code. For example:

```
<head><script>var host="{{url()}}"</script>
```

But, if you are listening to `click` on a `<a href`, it'd be best to prevent the bubbling of the event. Like so:

```
$('.getRequestReadMessage').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

for Laravel Controller's method, there are a number of ways.
for example:

```
dd(Input::get("readValue"));
dd(Request::get("readValue"));
dd($request->input("readValue");
```

Either should do the trick

The Routes is most likely off too,The path needs the "unread" to work.

```
post('/messages/unread', '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\MessageController@getReadRequest');
```

Comment: If using Laravel 5 you can also do `request()->input('readValue')`

Comment: I might want to specify that when I click ".getRequestReadMessage", I get there error "ReferenceError: host is not defined" in console.

Comment: do this: `<head><script>var host="{{url()}}"</script>`, that way you should get the reference to your site visible in all JS globally

Comment: Ok, the error is gone. Now when I click it, nothing happens.

Comment: Check in firebug/chrometools whether the request is reaching your server. And if so, check the return body. If it went through, you should get the result of `dd`, otherwise, the error message.

Comment: That's a 500 error which means there is an internal server error now.  You are going to have to check out your error logs to see what the issue is.  Could be one of too many things for us to diagnose without seeing the error.

Comment: look into the "response" tab. You should get a bit more info from within there.

Comment: The response tab seems to only have my full markup. My original post has been updated with everything up to date, including the laravel error logs.

Comment: in your controller, put this at the top `use Input;`

Comment: Right, done. Now I don't get any errors in my log, but nothing happens once again. I do get a 200 error in console, however.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I do get an error in logs. http://codepaste.net/cttmrs

Answer (score 0):

Try tweaking your route to this:

```
Route::post('/messages/unread', '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\MessageController@getReadRequest');
```